# IF Logic test - Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to create a in and out sheet for COVID-19 tests for our company and I can't seem to get it to work.

[image: PICTURE_1]

I am trying to do If cell = IN then add, else minus from the number.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` function.

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"IN",B:B)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, how would I do minus though?

Comment: Not clear.. Could you make a proper sample data and expected result?

Comment: @BenHoward you can simply deduct another sumif from the above results using "out" as your criteria.